# Make watermark image lighter (more transparent)

Tags: watermark

I need to display my college logo as watermark in certificate only...
i tried with `\usepackage{draftwatermark}`
and

```
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics{filename}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.45}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0,1,0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{1}
```

.....everything is fine except lightness..image is displaying as it is...so the text is not visible .Is there any other commands.
for watermark certificate and lightness  should be  very low.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The title does'n seem very appropriate.  May I suggest you change it to something like "Make watermark image lighter"

Answer (score 7):

As you observe, `\SetWatermarkLightness` only really affects plain text part of the watermark.  Using `tikz` you can specify transparency, or rather `opacity`: value `0` will be invisible, `1` will give the usual image:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\SetWatermarkText{\tikz{\node[opacity=0.2]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}};}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.45}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0,1,0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to offer an alternative. The [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package internally uses TikZ and offers an `opacity` key exactly for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[firstpage=true]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics{example-image-a}},
angle=0,
scale=0.5,
color=black,
opacity=0.2
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `firstpage=true` to have the material in the first page of the document, but using the features provided by the package you can place the material in any other individual page you desire.

Answer (score 1):

This may help. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{scale=1, angle=0, opacity=0.15,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node at ([yshift=0pt, xshift=95pt]current page.center)
{\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{your-image.png}};\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\BgThispage
\lipsum[1-4]

\newpage
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```